# Apache beam SqlTransforms schema issue

Tags: hive, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam-sql

I'm trying to perform ETL which involves loading files from HDFS, apply transforms and write them to Hive. While using SqlTransforms for performing transformations by following [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/walkthrough/) doc, I'm encountering below issue. Can you please help?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getSchema when there is no schema
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getSchema(PCollection.java:328)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.schema.BeamPCollectionTable.<init>(BeamPCollectionTable.java:34)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.toTableMap(SqlTransform.java:105)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:90)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:471)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:339)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.SqlTest.runSqlTest(SqlTest.java:107)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.SqlTest.main(SqlTest.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code Snippet:

```
PCollection<String> data = p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()));

    if(options.getOutput().equals("hive")){
        Schema hiveTableSchema = Schema.builder()
                .addStringField("eid")
                .addStringField("name")
                .addStringField("salary")
                .addStringField("destination")
                .build();
          data.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Row>() {
              @ProcessElement
              public void processElement(@Element String input, OutputReceiver<Row> out){
                  String[] values = input.split(",");
                  System.out.println(values);
                  Row row = Row.withSchema(hiveTableSchema)
                                .addValues(values)
                                .build();
                  out.output(row);
              }
          })).apply(SqlTransform.query("select eid, destination from PCOLLECTION"))

                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Row, HCatRecord>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(@Element Row input, OutputReceiver<HCatRecord> out){
                        HCatRecord record = new DefaultHCatRecord(input.getFieldCount());
                        for(int i=0; i < input.getFieldCount(); i++){
                            record.set(i, input.getString(i));
                        }
                        out.output(record);
                    }
                        }))
                .apply("WriteData", HCatalogIO.write()
                        .withConfigProperties(configProperties)
                        .withDatabase("wmrpoc")
                        .withTable(options.getOutputTableName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the schema on the `PCollection`. In the walkthrough you linked there's `Create...withCoder()` that handles that. In your case schema cannot be inferred from your `ParDo`, the only information Beam potentially has looking at it is that it outputs the elements of type `Row` but there's no information available to it whether your `ParDo` even adheres to a single schema for all outputs. So you need to call `pcollection.setRowSchema()` before you apply `SqlTransform` to tell Beam what schema you're planning to get out of your conversion `ParDo`.

**Update**

And looks like most of what you're doing before `HCatalog` will likely eventually be simplified a lot, e.g. imagine you only need to specify something like `pipeline.apply(TextIO.readCsvRows(schema)).apply(sqlTransform)...`. In fact Beam SQL supports reading CSV files without extra conversion `ParDos` (through [`TextTableProvider`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/bdd0081b49f8e7df6733dc8e8bc90dda3efc6621/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/meta/provider/text/TextTableProviderTest.java#L43)) but it is not wired up to `SqlTransform` yet and only accessible through Beam SQL CLI

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. It solved above error but I now get a new one
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Property 'org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.planner.BeamRelDataTypeSystem' not valid for plugin type org.apache.calcite.rel.type.RelDataTypeSystem`

Comment: Update on trace
`An exception occured while executing the Jav
a class. java.lang.RuntimeException: Property 'org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.planner.BeamRelDataTypeSystem' not valid for plugin type org.apache.calcite.r
el.type.RelDataTypeSystem: Cannot cast org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.planner.BeamRelDataTypeSystem to org.apache.calcite.rel.type.RelDataTypeSystem -> [He
lp 1]`

Comment: Hm, not sure what is happening here, `BeamRelDataTypeSystem` is a subclass of `RelDataTypeSystem` ( https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a2b0ad14f1525d1a645cb26f5b8ec45692d9d54e/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/impl/planner/BeamRelDataTypeSystem.java#L24  . Are you building Beam SDK sources or using Beam as maven dependency?

Comment: As a maven dependency.
`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-sql</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>`
And the beam version is 2.7.0

Comment: I don't understand what can be causing this, filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5858 to follow up. Unfortunately I don't know of a workaround either at the moment :( I will update the answer when I figure it out